# Crontab command missing in Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, cron, package-management, troubleshooting, vagrant

I am using vagrant boxes for several tests and in this particular case it is the Fedora 31 box from [Bento](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/fedora-31) with VirtualBox. When trying to use the `crontab` command, I get an error that it is not found. A quick search with `locate` tells me that there is no cron system installed at all.

Is it a new default in Fedora 31 to not install cron at all by default, or is it the Bento project that might think this is a good idea?

On my Fedora Workstation the command is there, but it was there before as I upgraded from 28 I think to 31 over the years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the [Fedora Documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/monitoring-and-automation/Automating_System_Tasks/),

> Fedora comes with the following automated task utilities: cron, anacron, at, and batch.

However, [it appears](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/monitoring-and-automation/Automating_System_Tasks/#sect-Cron-Installing) that these need to be installed as they do not come included:

> Installing Cron and Anacron
>
> To install Cron and Anacron, you need to install the cronie package with Cron and the cronie-anacron package with Anacron (cronie-anacron is a sub-package of cronie).

```bsh
dnf install cronie cronie-anacron
```

See also: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Administration_Guide_Draft/Cron

If you look at the [setup scripts](https://github.com/chef/bento/tree/master/packer_templates/fedora) for those Vagrant boxes, you will see very little deviation from the base image.